# Multiple Images Selection

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Am making an application in WP7 using Windows Phone SDK 7.1 / C#

Am using photo chooser task. But I want to select 9 images and here I can select only one Image.

How can I select 9 images at a stretch?

Please Help me, here is my code:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    PhotoChooserTask photoChoserTask;
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    photoChoserTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
    photoChoserTask.Completed += 
             new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(photoChooserTask_Completed);
    }


void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
  if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
  {
     y.Text= (e.ChosenPhoto.Length.ToString());

    //Code to display the photo on the page in an image control named myImage.
    //System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = 
            //new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
    //bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
    //myImage.Source = bmp;
  }
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{       
    {
        try
        {
            photoChoserTask.Show();
        }
        catch (System.InvalidOperationException )
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred.");
        }
    }
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst `PhotoChooserTask` will only allow the user to select one image from their library (or capture a new one from their camera if you set `ShowCamera` to true) another option would be to continue to allow the user to iteratively select images and not allow them to continue until they have selected 9 (I believe that's the requirement you're after?)

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage {
    public class SelectedPhoto : IDisposable {
        public Stream Data { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public BitmapImage Image { get; private set; }

        public SelectedPhoto(string name, Stream photo) {
            Name = name;

            Data = new MemoryStream();
            photo.CopyTo(Data);

            Image = new BitmapImage();
            Image.SetSource(Data);
        }

        public void Dispose() {
            Data.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private List<SelectedPhoto> _selectedPhotos = new List<SelectedPhoto>();
    private PhotoChooserTask photoChoserTask;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage() {
        InitializeComponent();
        photoChoserTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
        photoChoserTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(photoChooserTask_Completed);

        ProcessImages.IsEnabled = false;
        ImageListBox.ItemsSource = _selectedPhotos
    }


    void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e) {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK) {
            _selectedPhotos.Add(new SelectedPhoto(e.OriginalFileName, e.ChosenPhoto);

            Button.IsEnabled = _selectedPhotos.Count < 9;
            ProcessImages.IsEnabled = _selectedPhotos.Count == 9;
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        {
            try {
                photoChoserTask.Show();
            } catch (System.InvalidOperationException) {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred.");
            }
        }
    }

    private void ProcessImages_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        MessageBox.Show("Doing something with your images... please wait...");
    }
}
```

In your XAML rather than having a single Image you'd want to put an Image inside a `ListBox`'s `DataTemplate` and show all of the user's currently entered images (probably with an option to erase an image and add a different image instead). Eg;

```
    <ListBox x:Name="ImageListBox">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <Button x:Name="ProcessImages" Click="ProcessImages_Click" />
```

If the requirement is to have *up to* 9 images, I'd prefer this approach, over a custom multi-select image selector, for a few reasons reasons;

1. It provides the user with a consistent user experience - the same as they'd get in any other app
2. By making use of the `MediaLibrary` your application will require the `ID_CAP_MEDIALIB` capability (Shows up as "Access media library", I believe).
3. I'd find this method a bit less work than a full blown media choser.

Comment: am getting Two errors in that....
please help if you can


Error 1 The name 'ProcessImages' does not exist in the current context 


Error 2 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' does not contain a definition for 'ItemsSource' and no extension method 'ItemsSource' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I've added example XAML for the `Button` and `ListBox` that I was referring to.

Comment: Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Controls.Control.IsEnabled.get'

Comment: I presume that's happening at `Button.IsEnabled = _selectedPhotos.Count < 9;`? `Button` in this case is an example name of a control that you want to enable / disable.

Answer (score 8):

I've release a MultiPhotoChooser on CodePlex for WP8.0 
(At least works on 8.0 because that's the platform I developed on.)

Feel free to download it and try it out

https://multiphotochooser.codeplex.com/

Here's how it looks like :

[image: Media Library in Sweetshot App]

Please give me a thumbs up if it helped you for building the feature you need.
Thanks.

Comment: Nice one. Keep it up! :)

Comment: I will try it in my new App and send you some feedback. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks bro, its a superb application

Answer (score 3):

**PhotoChooserTask is used to user to select one photo,** To allow the user to use multiple photos, **you have to create your own UI**, with the list of images displayed.
**you can use XNA.MediaLibrary to access the existing images of devices** and show.
Also provide interface to user to choose multiple images.

Answer (score 1):

The PhotoChooserTask is meant to let the user select only one photo. I guess you'll have to create a Page or Control in which you show all available photos / pictures and make them multi-selectable with a CheckBox or something and return that result to your code.