# Select multiple images from the Photo library in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone

As i am working on an windows Phone 8 app which requires to select multiple images from the Photo library of phone to do this i have used the PhotoChooserTask but it returns a single image can anyone suggest me other class or method to extract multiple images thanks in advance.

Comment: Close, WP7; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614331/multiple-images-selection

Comment: Another option is to create your own photo chooser Page. You can access all phone's pictures from `MediaLibrary.Pictures`